# Passing a static list to a predicate

Tags: prolog

I'm a beginner in Prolog and I'm having trouble understanding why this code does not work as I expect.

Here is my database:

```
p([1, 2, 3]).
isFirstElement(X, [H|_]) :- X = H.
```

Here is my console:

```
?- p(X).
X = [1, 2, 3].

?- isFirstElement(1, p(X)).
false.

?- isFirstElement(1, [1, 2, 3]).
true.
```

The first call to isFirstElement doesn't return true and I not sure why. Is p(X) not being evaluated? How would I do this properly?

Comment: with unification: `?- p(X), isFirstElement(1, X).`

Comment: To be clear, in Prolog, `p(X)` isn't a function that returns the list. It is a predicate that succeeds or fails depending upon `X`, and will instantiate `X` with values that cause it to succeed. So `isFirstelement(1, p(X))` doesn't mean what you think, and `p(X)` is not evaluated in that context. It's just a term being passed as an argument to `isFirstElement/2` in that case. As CapelliC points, out, you must first instantiate `X` with a successful query to `p(X)`, then call `isFirstElement(1, X)`.

Comment: @CapelliC That returns: `X = [1, 2, 3].` which inexplicably means true right?

Comment: *That returns: `X = [1, 2, 3].` "inexplicably" means true*??  `p(X)` doesn't return a value like functions do. When you query, `p(X), isFirstElement(1, X).`, Prolog first tries to make `p(X)` succeed, which it does so by unifying `X` with `[1, 2, 3]`, then it moves on to try to make `isFirstElement(1, X)` succeed, which it also manages to do so. Thus the `true` result. Prolog in this case shows you what variable instantiations led to the result, thus the `X = [1, 2, 3]` in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of `isFirstElement` should be a list, not a predicate.

`isFirstElement(1, X)`